# String comparison in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have two strings, which I need to compare for equality.

String 1 is created in this way:

```
var
    inBuf: array[0..IN_BUF_SIZE] of WideChar;
    stringBuilder : TStringBuilder;
    mystring1:string;
    ...
begin

stringBuilder := TStringBuilder.Create;

for i := startOfInterestingPart to endOfInterestingPart do
begin
  stringBuilder.Append(inBuf[i]);
end;

mystring1 := stringBuilder.ToString();
stringBuilder.Free;
```

String 2 is a constant string `'ABC'`.

When string 1 is displayed in a debug console, it is equal to 'ABC'. But the comparisons

1. `AnsiCompareText(mystring1, 'ABC')`
2. `mystring1 = 'ABC'`
3. `CompareStr(mystring1, 'ABC')`

all report inequality.

I suppose that I need to convert string 2 (`'ABC'`) to the same type as the string 1.

How can I do that?

**Update 26.09.2012:**

`aMessage` is displayed in the log output as {FDI-MSG-START-Init-FDI-MSG-END}

Here's the code for printing the length of strings:

```
StringToWideChar('{FDI-MSG-START-Init-FDI-MSG-END}', convString, iNewSize);

...

OutputDebugString(PChar('Len (aMessage): ' + IntToStr(Length(aMessage))));
OutputDebugString(PChar('Len (original constant): ' + IntToStr(Length('{FDI-MSG-START-Init-FDI-MSG-END}'))));
OutputDebugString(PChar('Len (convString): ' + IntToStr(Length(convString))));
```

And here's the log output:

```
[3580] Len (aMessage): 40
[3580] Len (original constant): 32
[3580] Len (convString): 0
```

Comment: 1) what is mystring.length ?
2) if length the same - make a loop, char by char, which chars is same and when it is different.
3) if/when found different characters, compare Word(char) for both strings.

I guess you do understand that "ABC" and "АВС" have no single common letter.

Comment: *convert string 2 ('ABC') to the same type as the string 1* -- i see no need in that, but if you insist -- *var mystring1,mystring2:string; ... mystring2 := 'ABC';*

Comment: *AnsiCompareText(aMessage, 'ABC')* what do you compare ? aMessage or mystring1 ???

Comment: aMessage is equal to mystring1. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Now a strange thing happened. On one machine `AnsiCompareText(mystring1, 'ABC')` reports equality, on another not. In both cases mystring1 is received from a C# application (on both machines, the C# application runs in Visual Studio 10). Only the operating system differs - on the machine, where it works, it's Windows 7, on the other machie (where it doesn't work) it' Windows XP Professional, version 2002, Service Pack 3.

Comment: *In both cases mystring1 is received from a C# application*
Then compare content of input buffer on both machines. And what about details from top comment ?

Comment: Ad top comment: See "Update 26.09.2012".

Comment: what are convString, iNewSize ??? they never been mentioned before.
Looks like aMessage has #0 and somethign more after 1st 32 chars.
is Copy(aMessage,1,32) equal to original ?
What are - char by char - aMessage letters 33 .. 40 ?

Comment: `convString` is generated using `StringToWideChar('{FDI-MSG-START-Init-FDI-MSG-END}', convString, iNewSize);`.

Comment: Thanks, Captain! i googled what is STWC. But that does not answer 1) what relation has convString to initial question and initial sample if any? 2) what type is convString? 3)what value has iNewSize ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're keeping garbage data in your wide string after the meaningful part, in your update, `Length(aMessage)` returns 40, while your source string's length is 32.

In Delphi a wide string is COM BSTR compatible, meaning it can hold null characters, a null does not terminate it, it keeps its length at a negative offset of the character data. A possible null character in it helps it to be converted to other string types, but it doesn't alter its own termination.

Consider the below,

```
const
  Source = '{FDI-MSG-START-Init-FDI-MSG-END}';
var
  ws: WideString;
  size: Integer;
begin
  size := 40;
  SetLength(ws, size);
  StringToWideChar(Source, PWideChar(ws), size);

  // the below assertion fails when uncommented
//  Assert(CompareStr(Source, ws) = 0);

  ws := PWideChar(ws);  // or SetLength(ws, Length(Source));
  // this assertion does not fail
  Assert(CompareStr(Source, ws) = 0);
end;
```